# Reference request: a survey of (linear) Krein-Rutman theory

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory, order-theory, positivity, banach-lattices

I'm looking for a survey article or book chapter where a rather exhaustive treatment of the Krein-Rutman theory of positive linear operators an ordered Banach spaces is given.

**Motivation.** Some explanation is probably required. Classicly, one finds two types of "Krein-Rutman theorems", and many versions thereof, in the literature:

Let $X$ be a real Banach space that is ordered by a closed cone $X_+$ (i.e., $\alpha X_+ + \beta X_+ \subseteq X$ for all $\alpha, \beta \in [0,\infty)$, and $X_+ \cap (-X_+) = \{0\}$). Let $T: X \to X$ be a bounded linear operator which is *positive* in the sense that $TX_+ \subseteq X_+$.

**Theorem 1.** (*"Weak version"*) Assume that $X_+$ is total (i.e. its span is dense in $X$). If $T$ is compact, then:

- The spectral radius $r(T)$ is in the spectrum of $T$.
- If $r(T) > 0$, then $r(T)$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ with an eigenvector in $X_+$, and an eigenvalue of the dual operator $T'$ with an eigenvector in the dual cone $X_+'$.

**Theorem 2.** (*"Strong version"*) Assume that $X_+$ has non-empty topological interior $\operatorname{int}(X_+)$ in $X$ and that $T$ is compact and *strongly positive* in the sense that $Tx \in \operatorname{int}(X_+)$ for every $0 \not= x \in X_+$. Then:

- $r(T) > 0$.
- The eigenvalue $r(T)$ is algebraically simple, and the corresponding eigenspace is spanned by a vector in $\operatorname{int}(X_+)$.
- $r(T)$ is the only spectral value of $T$ with modulus $r(T)$.
- $r(T)$ is the only eigenvalue of $T$ that admits an eigenvector in $X_+$.

These results are easy to find in numerous places in the literature, and so are various improvements thereof (for instance, "compact" is obviously too strong an assumption; it suffices if the essential spectral radius $r_e(T)$ is strictly smaller than $r(T)$).

However, I find many treatments of this circle of ideas in the literature rather unsatisfactory, for the following reasons:

- These results are typically used as auxiliary results for other purposes (for instance, in PDE theory), so they are often presented in an ad-hoc manner rather in a structure theoretic way.
- The underlying ideas are typically not exploited in a comprehensive way. For instance, it is easy to prove a version of Theorem 1 if the compactness assumption is replaced with the assumption that $T/r(T)$ is weakly almost periodic and that $T$ has an eigenvalue of modulus $r(T)$; but I have not seen this anywhere, yet.
- In the setting of general ordered Banach spaces, most versions of Theorem 2 that I have encountered (with some exceptions, though) use the rather strong - and, imho artificial - assumption that the cone has non-empty interior. On the other hand, though, in the setting of Banach lattices, an entire Krein-Rutman theory (which is, in the context of Banach lattices more often called Perron-Frobenius theory) is available without this assumption (the assumption "strong positivity" then has to be replaced with some kind of irreducibility assumption; see, for instance, Section~V.5 in H. H. Schaefer's book "Banach lattices and positive operators (1974)"). I find this to be a strange state of affairs since it seems desirable to view the corresponding results on Banach lattices and Theorem 2 above as special cases of the same general theory.

**The question.** So my question is, in more precise terms: Is there a survey article or book chapter about linear Krein-Rutman theory in ordered Banach spaces that satisfies the following requirements:

(i) It uses a *structure theoretic approach*, i.e. it does not focus on ad-hoc methods but rather on theory building.

(ii) It is *comprehensive* in the sense that it (a) presents very general versions of the theorems rather than special cases (for instance, it assumes $r_e(T) < r(T)$ rather than compactness of $T$) and (b) tries to exhaust the available methods and to provide counterexamples which demonstrate optimality of results.

(iii) It is *unifying* in the sense that it does not assume the interior of the positive cone to be non-empty unless really necessary - such that the known results on Banach lattices fit into the general framework. It particular, it should also contain a theory a irreducible operators on ordered Banach spaces.

**Remarks.**

- If you know a survey which meets only a proper (and non-empty) subset of the requirements (i)-(iii), I will still be happy to learn about it (although it does not completely answer the question).
- The only reference that I know which comes somewhat close is the Appendix of H. H. Schaefer's book "Topological vector spaces (1971)". It satisfies requirement (i), but then, again, it falls in some respects short of (ii) and, to a large extent, also of (iii).

**What this question is *not* about.** Please note:

- I am not asking for single generalizations of the above theorems. I know that there are plenty of them, and I know where to find many of them. I am looking for a *survey* where theses results and generalizations are discussed in a single place.
- Non-linear Krein-Rutman theory is interesting and important, but it is not part of this question. (But, of course, a survey which covers both the linear and the non-linear theory would qualify as an answer, as long as the linear part is also treated in detail.)
- I am not asking for literature that focusses merely on Banach lattices (or on ordered Banach space with the Riesz decomposition property).
- I am not asking for ideas or methods how one could generalize, for instance, Theorem 2 to a theory that fits requirement (iii). I am aware of such methods, but I would like to have a citable reference where they are presented.